# MySQL - is it possible to update only part of value from current column?

Tags: mysql

Here is an example table on which I would like to execute a query:

```
Structure of table_1
number | photos (CHAR,4)
1234   | 1210
```

I would like to update value from column `photos`, but without changing the whole value. I would like change, for example, only third character to "2" without knowing the whole value. How can I do that?

*I know I could do that in this way described below, but the problem is the value may be variable and it is a column type CHAR, not INT.*

```
UPDATE table_1 SET photos = (photos + 10) where number='1234'
```

Comment: There is no such thing like a UPDATE PARTIAL or UPDATE BYTE(2). Each update will actually write the new value in place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes with [mid](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_mid), [left](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_left) and [right](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_right) functions because photos is a type char:

```
UPDATE table_1 SET photos = 
 concat(
   left( photos, 2),
   '1',
   right( photos, 1)
 )
 where number='1234'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use concat(), left() and substring()

The example above would look like this:

```
update table_1
set photos = concat(left(photos, 2), "2", substring(photos, 4))
where number = '1234'
```

The advantage to this over left/right, is this will work for variable lengths of "photos".

Looking at it more generally, if you want to set the xth position to "2":

```
update table_1
set photos = concat(left(photos, x-1), "2", substring(photos, x+1))
where number = '1234'
```

(NOTE: I don't have MySQL running right now so I can't test the above.  There are certain to be off-by-one errors which should be easy for your to correct)

Comment: After execute your example from value "0000" I wanted to have "0010" I got value "1", but thanks for help. Only way with 'left' and 'right' works for me.

Answer (score 0):

If the column contains only numbers then the example you gave would work. The value will be converted to an integer, added to, and then converted back.

You might want to explain your reasoning for wanting to do this though. It seems a bit strange.

Comment: For storing user settings I want to update only part of string in case while user updated only one setting, and these settings are not in one page so I can't merge them before add.